# Assigning complex values to numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This gives the expected result

```
x = random.rand(1) + random.rand(1)*1j
print x.dtype
print x, x.real, x.imag
```

and this works

```
C = zeros((2,2),dtype=complex)
C[0,0] = 1+1j
print C
```

but if we change it to

```
C[0,0] = 1+1j + x
```

I get "TypeError: can't convert complex to float".

If we now omit the explicit `dtype = complex`, I get "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence".

Can someone explain what's going on, and how to do this without errors? I'm lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To insert complex `x` or `x + something` into `C`, you apparently need to treat it as if it were an array, so either index into `x` or assign it to a slice of `C`:

```
>>> C
array([[ 0.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
       [ 0.+0.j,  0.+0.j]])
>>> C[0, 0:1] = x
>>> C
array([[ 0.47229555+0.7957525j,  0.00000000+0.j       ],
       [ 0.00000000+0.j       ,  0.00000000+0.j       ]])
>>> C[1, 1] = x[0] + 1+1j
>>> C
array([[ 0.47229555+0.7957525j,  0.00000000+0.j       ],
       [ 0.00000000+0.j       ,  1.47229555+1.7957525j]])
```

It looks like NumPy isn't handling this case correctly. Consider submitting a bug report.

Comment: but why `a=np.arange(4).reshape((2,2)); b=np.array([100]); a[0,0]=b` does not give such an error?

Comment: @zhangxaochen Good Q, maybe the behavior of complex arrays is even buggier than I though. I never use those :)

Comment: Interesting. `C[0,0] = random.rand(1)` is fine, but `C[0,0] = random.rand(1)+random.rand(1)*1j` is not. Why does `x` become an array when we add the imaginary part to it? I thought complex numbers were a native data type in python, not just implemented through arrays?

Comment: @gibson `random.rand(1)` is an array.

Comment: @larsmans If that's the case, `C[0,0] = random.rand(1)` shouldn't work, but it does. I'm still confused.

Comment: @gibson I must admit, so am I. Perhaps this is NumPy bug/corner case.

Comment: @larsmans Ok, at least it's good to know that I'm not just missing something obvious.

Comment: @larmans Thank you for updating your initial answer to correspond with what we've uncovered. I've submitted an issue ( https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4379 ), so we'll see what happens.

Answer (score 50):

Actually, none of the proposed solutions worked in my case (Python 2.7.6, NumPy 1.8.2). 
But I've found out, that change of `dtype` from `complex` (standard Python library) to `numpy.complex_` may help:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = 1 + 2 * 1j
>>> C = np.zeros((2,2),dtype=np.complex_)
>>> C
array([[ 0.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
       [ 0.+0.j,  0.+0.j]])
>>> C[0,0] = 1+1j + x
>>> C
array([[ 2.+3.j,  0.+0.j],
       [ 0.+0.j,  0.+0.j]])
```

Answer (score 3):

I used [astype](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) to change the type to complex and it worked in my case (Python 3), although I am not sure whether it is the best way. One example:

```
import numpy as np
c2 = np.empty([2,2]).astype(complex)
c2[0] = 5j+2
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
x = 1.0
y = 1.5
```

C[i,j] = complex(x, y)