# How to turn array of array into single high dimension array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Python script and somehow in my Numpy calculation I got a variable like this:

```
In [72]: a
Out[72]: 
array([[ array([-0.02134025+0.1445159j , -0.02136137+0.14458584j,
       -0.02138250+0.14465578j, ..., -0.01568173+0.12424096j,
       -0.01569507+0.12429295j, -0.01570842+0.12434494j]),
        array([-0.14451590+0.97865975j, -0.14458584+0.97863863j,
       -0.14465578+0.9786175j , ..., -0.12424096+0.98431827j,
       -0.12429295+0.98430493j, -0.12434494+0.98429158j])],
       [ array([-0.14451590+0.97865975j, -0.14458584+0.97863863j,
       -0.14465578+0.9786175j , ..., -0.12424096+0.98431827j,
       -0.12429295+0.98430493j, -0.12434494+0.98429158j]),
        array([ 0.02134025-0.1445159j ,  0.02136137-0.14458584j,
        0.02138250-0.14465578j, ...,  0.01568173-0.12424096j,
        0.01569507-0.12429295j,  0.01570842-0.12434494j])]], dtype=object)

In [73]: np.shape(a)
Out[73]: (2, 2)
```

So it's basically a 2D array where each element is an array of length `n`, but somehow `a` is not a 3D array of shape `(2,2,n)`. You can see the extra word `array` in each element in the print out. I don't understand how this happened but I'd like to turn `a` into a 3D array of shape `(2,2,n)` because I have other `(2,2,n)` variables and they're not inter-operable. (If I can turn other `(2,2,n)` arrays into same thing as `a` that would probably work too, I guess).

For example an array of shape `(2,2,3)` like this won't have the extra `array` wording print out in each element. And the shape is `(2,2,3)` not `(2,2)`.

```
In [75]: np.zeros((2,2,3))
Out[75]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

I tried `np.asarray(a)` and `a.reshape((2,2,))` but they didn't do anything, I guess it's already an array.

---

**Update**: This is the similar code that generates something like `a`:

```
In [80]: T1 = np.array([ [np.linspace(0,1,5),0],[0,1] ])

In [81]: T1
Out[81]: 
array([[array([ 0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.75,  1.  ]), 0],
       [0, 1]], dtype=object)

In [82]: T2 = np.identity(2)

In [83]: T2
Out[83]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])

In [84]: T3 = np.dot(T1,T2)

In [85]: T3
Out[85]: 
array([[array([ 0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.75,  1.  ]),
        array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])],
       [0.0, 1.0]], dtype=object)

In [86]: T4 = np.dot(T2,T3)

In [87]: T4
Out[87]: 
array([[array([ 0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.75,  1.  ]),
        array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])],
       [array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])]], dtype=object)
```

The elements are same length and `asarray` doesn't work.

```
In [88]: np.asarray(T4)
Out[88]: 
array([[array([ 0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.75,  1.  ]),
        array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])],
       [array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that generated `a`?  When I load the contents of `a` exactly as you've listed them, the resulting `shape` is `(2,2,7)`.

Comment: I suspect your individual arrays are not the same length. However, it would be helpful if you showed us how this was generated.

Comment: `a = np.asarray(a)` if this doesn't work your arrays are inconsistent.

Comment: This kind of thing is something you should fix in the code path that creates `a`, not after you have it. It tends to indicate a bug somewhere in the code leading up to the array's creation.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `T1`? That seems to be the source of this problem, you should start working with a real multidimensional array.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because I can do `np.dot(T1,T2)`. If I start with a 3d array as T1, then it won't allow multiplication between `(2,2,n)` and `(2,2)`. It won't broadcast the same way. The thing is, in the real code, when `T2` is created, the length of the 3rd dimension of `T1` is yet defined, and this mitigate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is caused by the `complex` data type you are using. If you look carefully at your array, you can spot, that the `dtype` of the inner array is `object` and not `complex` as it should be. Please check if this is solved by setting the `dtype` of the inner arrays properly during the calculation/creation.

If this does not help, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016847/assigning-complex-values-to-numpy-arrays) SO thread. It's about a similar problem and might offer you an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is, as noted, a 2d array, where each element is a 1d array.

`np.array(...)` tries to create as high a dimensional array as it can.  But if the subelements (or lists) vary in size it can't, and resorts to making a object array (or in some cases raising an error). Your `T1` is this kind of array.

If your subarrays are all the same shape, we can convert it in to a 3d array.

I can't recreate your `T4` with a copynpaste because `np.array` makes a 3d array:

```
In [35]: array = np.array
In [36]: T4= array([[array([ 0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.75,  1.  ]),
    ...:         array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])],
    ...:        [array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1
    ...: .])]], dtype=object)
    ...:        
In [37]: T4
Out[37]: 
array([[[0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],

       [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]], dtype=object)
```

But with your `dot` sequence:

```
In [41]: T1 = np.array([ [np.linspace(0,1,5),0],[0,1] ])
In [42]:  T2 = np.identity(2)
In [43]: T3 = np.dot(T1,T2)
In [44]: T4 = np.dot(T2,T3)
```

But I can convert it into one array with `concatenate`.  Actually `stack` is best here.  But first I have to turn it into a 1d array (4,).  `np.vstack` would also work.  Effectively it is now a list of 4 5-element arrays:

```
In [47]: np.stack(T4.ravel())
Out[47]: 
array([[ 0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.75,  1.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ]])
In [48]: _.reshape(2,2,-1)
Out[48]: 
array([[[ 0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.75,  1.  ],
        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]],

       [[ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
        [ 1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ]]])
```

Usually I recreate arrays like `T4` by making a blank object array, e.g. `a = np.zeros((2,2),object)`, and then filling the slots from a list.  But posters also get them from third party packages.  So this `stack` trick is a useful one to know.