# numpy slicing inner array of a 2D array in one go

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

consider the below array (EDIT: the format of the array is because I get this data from another source, basically the data is nested list of lists of unequal elements)

```
eg = array([
   [ list(['Vehicle Sales Anfavea units','Brazil','184,815.00'])],
   [ list(['Commodity Price Index MoM % m/m', 'Brazil', '-0.58'])],
   [ list(['Commodity Price Index YoY % y/y', 'Brazil', '0.54'])]
 ], dtype=object)
```

how can i slice this array in a `single attempt` to get last two elements in each row? my desired output should be something like

```
([
['Brazil','184,815.00'],
['Brazil', '-0.58'],
['Brazil', ''0.54']
])
```

Comment: Is you one-element list `[list(['Vehicle Sales Anfavea units','Brazil','184,815.00'])]` intentional or did you actually mean `['Vehicle Sales Anfavea units','Brazil','184,815.00']`? In the latter case, the answer is `eg[:,[1,2]]`. In the former case, `eg[:,0,[1,2]]`.

Comment: This is not a 2D array. You may want to familiarize yourself with the syntax to construct lists and arrays before you go further; the `list` calls are redundant, and the brackets around the `list` calls are most likely not doing anything you want.

Comment: i get the point, but the format of this array is because I am getting the data from another source.

Comment: Are you saying this is the `repr` of the array? That's very different from if you had actually executed the code you posted.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would have said `dtype=object` in the `repr` if it had that explicit `list` notation, though.

Comment: My bad, the data has 'dtype=object' i did not include that in the original sample, but have edited it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the display of a (3,1) object array, containing 3 lists:

```
In [168]: arr = np.zeros((3,1),object)
In [169]: arr[:,0]=[['Vehicle Sales Anfavea units','Brazil','184,815.00'],['Comm
     ...: odity Price Index MoM % m/m', 'Brazil', '-0.58'],['Commodity Price Ind
     ...: ex YoY % y/y', 'Brazil', '0.54']]
In [170]: arr
Out[170]: 
array([[list(['Vehicle Sales Anfavea units', 'Brazil', '184,815.00'])],
       [list(['Commodity Price Index MoM % m/m', 'Brazil', '-0.58'])],
       [list(['Commodity Price Index YoY % y/y', 'Brazil', '0.54'])]], dtype=object)
```

A simple copy-n-paste creates a (3,1,3) array objects (strings); not a 2d array of lists.

Since you want a slice of the lists, you'll have use a list comprehension

```
In [171]: [a[-2:] for a in arr.ravel()]
Out[171]: [['Brazil', '184,815.00'], ['Brazil', '-0.58'], ['Brazil', '0.54']]
In [172]: np.array(_)
Out[172]: 
array([['Brazil', '184,815.00'],
       ['Brazil', '-0.58'],
       ['Brazil', '0.54']],
      dtype='<U10')
```

Notice that this final array is (3,2) string dtype, not an object array of lists.

Another approach is to turn it into a 2d string array, and index that:

```
In [174]: np.stack(arr.ravel())
Out[174]: 
array([['Vehicle Sales Anfavea units', 'Brazil', '184,815.00'],
       ['Commodity Price Index MoM % m/m', 'Brazil', '-0.58'],
       ['Commodity Price Index YoY % y/y', 'Brazil', '0.54']],
      dtype='<U31')
In [175]: _.shape
Out[175]: (3, 3)
In [176]: __[:,-2:]
Out[176]: 
array([['Brazil', '184,815.00'],
       ['Brazil', '-0.58'],
       ['Brazil', '0.54']],
      dtype='<U31')
```

More about this use of `stack` at [How to turn array of array into single high dimension array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46064280/how-to-turn-array-of-array-into-single-high-dimension-array)

---

To keep the object array of lists structure, an inplace replacement might be easiest:

```
In [180]: arr1=arr.copy()
In [181]: arr1.shape
Out[181]: (3, 1)
In [182]: for a in arr1.ravel():
     ...:     a[:] = a[-2:]
     ...:     
In [183]: arr1
Out[183]: 
array([[list(['Brazil', '184,815.00'])],
       [list(['Brazil', '-0.58'])],
       [list(['Brazil', '0.54'])]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: `np.array(arr.tolist())` is a convenient way to turn an object array of lists into a regular array, though I can't say whether it's the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so taking your data as is,

```
import numpy as np
eg = np.array([
   [ list(['Vehicle Sales Anfavea units','Brazil','184,815.00'])],
   [ list(['Commodity Price Index MoM % m/m', 'Brazil', '-0.58'])],
   [ list(['Commodity Price Index YoY % y/y', 'Brazil', '0.54'])]
 ], dtype=object)
```

You can simply run following one liner to get needed values.

```
x = [ i.tolist() for i in [i[0][1:] for i in eg] ]
```

`[i[0][1:] for i in eg]` parses list of list and `i.tolist()` converts `np.array` value to a `list`

```
>>> 
>>> x
[['Brazil', '184,815.00'], ['Brazil', '-0.58'], ['Brazil', '0.54']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, you'll get some "nesting" though:

```
In [1]: from numpy import array

In [2]: eg = array([
   ...:    [ list(['Vehicle Sales Anfavea units','Brazil','184,815.00'])],
   ...:    [ list(['Commodity Price Index MoM % m/m', 'Brazil', '-0.58'])],
   ...:    [ list(['Commodity Price Index YoY % y/y', 'Brazil', '0.54'])]
   ...:  ], dtype=object)

In [3]: eg[:,:,-2:]
Out[3]:
array([[['Brazil', '184,815.00']],

       [['Brazil', '-0.58']],

       [['Brazil', '0.54']]], dtype=object)
```

You can however "squeeze" it:

```
In [4]: import numpy as np

In [5]: np.squeeze(eg[:,:,-2:])
Out[5]:
array([['Brazil', '184,815.00'],
       ['Brazil', '-0.58'],
       ['Brazil', '0.54']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: You didn't start with the same array; your's is (3,1,3), not (3,2) with lists.

Comment: I copy pasted his example.

Answer (score 0):

Your array may look like

```
array([
   [ list(['Vehicle Sales Anfavea units','Brazil','184,815.00'])],
   [ list(['Commodity Price Index MoM % m/m', 'Brazil', '-0.58'])],
   [ list(['Commodity Price Index YoY % y/y', 'Brazil', '0.54'])]
 ], dtype=object)
```

but running that as code will not reproduce your array, and trying to slice the sublists as if they were part of the array's structure won't work.

You have a 2-dimensional array of object dtype whose elements are lists. Since version 1.13, NumPy will explicitly show `list(...)` for lists inside an array in the `repr` view, but NumPy won't see the `list(...)` notation if you try to execute the `repr` representation as code, and it will infer the depth of the array from the input, usually not preserving the lists.

---

You need to eliminate the redundant singleton dimension, convert the array of lists to a normal multidimensional array, and then slice:

```
eg = eg[:, 0]
eg = numpy.array(eg.tolist())
eg = eg[:, 1:]
```