# adding complex value in 3 Dimensional Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a data type numpy.complex128 for added to matrix 3D (3 Dimensional Array). I write script like below. when I run the script there was a warning like "ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part", and the result of 3D matrix was just real value, not include imaginary value. How can I fix it if I want to add both real and imaginary in that matrix 3D?

```
for i in range (0, nper):
    zz = []
    x = np.zeros((nl,2,2))
    for j in range (0, nl):
        z = np.sqrt(phi*amu*res[j]/per[i])
        zz.append(complex(z,z))
        exp0 = np.exp((-2)*zz[j]/res[j]*thi[j])
        exp1 = complex(1,0)+exp0
        exp2 = complex(1,0)-exp0
    #matrix 3D
        x[j,0,0] = exp1
        x[j,0,1] = zz[j]*exp2
        x[j,1,0] = exp2/zz[j]
        x[j,1,1] = exp1
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. There are all kinds of undefined variables. Nevertheless, I guess the problem is that you did not initialize the array as complex.

Comment: actually I have the complete code in my script, and the problem is just when I run the matrix 3D. if there is oke, may you give me an example how to initialize the array as complex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning complex values to numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016847/assigning-complex-values-to-numpy-arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably missed to tell numpy that your `x` array is complex:

```
x = np.zeros((nl, 2, 2), dtype=np.complex128)
```